# C# How to make a TCP server raise an event/callback when there is new data from the client

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, networking

So basically I want my server to raise an event (or a callback) when a connected client sends data. I can't come up with a solution to this problem and can't find anything online after days of searching.
What I've thought of was making an asynchronous foreach loop that looped through all the connected users, and check if there is any data to be read on each one (using TcpClient.Avaliable, but a network stream could also check this) but an infinite loop like this without any stop would be bad practice and use an insane amount of resources (from what I understand at least, I am new to threading and networking).
There is logic I need to be executed whenever the server gets data from a client (in this case a message, because it's a chat application), basically broadcast it to every other user, but I just can't find out how to detect if any user has sent data so that it raises an event to broadcast the message, log the message, etc...
Please be "soft" with the explanations as I am new to threading/networking and ty in advance.

As per request here is my code, take note that it is prototype-y and a bit unfinished, but I'm sure it gets the point across:

```
    //Properties
    public List<User> ConnectedUsers { get; private set; } = new List<User>();
    public TcpListener listener { get; set; }
    public bool IsListeningForConnections { get; set; }
    public int DisconnectionCheckInterval { get; set; } //in seconds

    //Events
    public event EventHandler<ServerEventArgs> UserConnected;
    public event EventHandler<ServerEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    public NetworkManager()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.86"), 6000); //binds // TODO: Change to: user input / prop file
        DisconnectionCheckInterval = 10;
        IsListeningForConnections = false;
    }

    public async void StartListeningForConnections()
    {
        IsListeningForConnections = true;
        listener.Start();

        while (IsListeningForConnections)
        {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.TcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            OnUserConnected(newUser); // raises/triggers the event
        }
    }

    public void StartListeningForDisconnections()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer disconnectionIntervalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(DisconnectionCheckInterval * 1000);
        //TODO: setup event
        //disconnectionIntervalTimer.Elasped += ;
        disconnectionIntervalTimer.AutoReset = true;
        disconnectionIntervalTimer.Enabled = true;
        //disconnectionIntervalTimer.Stop();
        //disconnectionIntervalTimer.Dispose();
    }

    public async void StartListeningForData()
    {
        //??????????
    }

    public async void SendData(string data, TcpClient recipient)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            NetworkStream stream = recipient.GetStream();
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //await
            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch { } //TODO: handle exception when message couldn't be sent (user disconnected)
    }

    public string ReceiveData(TcpClient sender)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = sender.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0');
        }
        catch
        {
            return null; //TODO: handle exception when message couldn't be read (user disconnected)
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnUserConnected(User user)
    {
        ConnectedUsers.Add(user);
        UserConnected?.Invoke(this, new ServerEventArgs() { User = user });
    }

    protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(User user, Message message) //needs trigger
    {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new ServerEventArgs() { User = user, Message = message });
    }
```

basically a different class will call all the 3 classes that start with "StartListeningForX", then one of the 3 corresponding events are raised when one of the checks goes through (disconnection/connection/new message), and process that data, I just can't get my hands on how to call an event when a new message arrives for each user.

Comment: Can you show us your code please? It would be helpful to narrow down the options if we had something to look at.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication

Comment: done, added the code @Train hope it is helpful

Comment: Do you have access to the client as well? Because there are easier ways of sending notifications like webhooks or signal R depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I've thought of was making an asynchronous foreach loop that looped through all the connected users, and check if there is any data to be read on each one (using TcpClient.Avaliable, but a network stream could also check this) but an infinite loop like this without any stop would be bad practice and use an insane amount of resources

The standard practice is to have an "infinite" loop for each connected client, so that there is always a read going on every socket. I put "infinite" in quotes because it will actually eventually stop; either by reading 0 bytes (indicating end of stream) or by receiving an exception (indicating a broken connection).

> I am new to threading/networking

It's funny how often I see developers trying to learn networking and threading at the same time. Let me be clear: threading and TCP/IP sockets are *both* extremely complicated and take quite a bit of time to learn all the sharp corners. Trying to learn *both* of these topics at once is insane. I strongly recommend choosing *one* of them to learn about (I'd recommend threading first), and only after that one is mastered, proceed to the other.

Comment: Threading and Networking are just extremely tied so usually when people get into networking they are forced to learn threading :) will definitely take your advice of studying both things more slowly and focused; to comment on your first statement though, standard practice is to have an "infinite" loop for each client, in a big big server, lets imagine, 100 connected users simultaneously spamming messages, wouldn't that just overload the threads? (I know it's possible, i.e MMO servers do it, not sure how complicated it is)

Comment: overload as in make the CPU really suffer. if so, is there a way to code the server in order for that not to happen (I thought by using the "thread for each client" method the CPU would die when a lot of users were doing busy traffic, but I might be wrong maybe the "thread for each client" is the only method)

Comment: Real-world servers are both multithreaded and asynchronous. So there's an infinite read loop, but since it reads asynchronously it only uses a thread when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

If you have access to the client side code, I'd consider using something like RabbitMQ, or a similar queue service. This allows to link the different apps together through a message broker or queue, and get messages/events real time.

There are functions you can call on event received.

Comment: I'm trying not to use 3rd party libraries/software, only my own logic and c# .net libraries